# cache: [GET /] miss

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, apache2, passenger

I have deployed my RoR app on VPS with Apache2 + Passenger. After configuring the app, when I hit the submit the request from the browser, I get "cache: [GET /] miss"  in my apache2/error.log

Please help me understand why am I getting this error. I  have been struggling with this error for a day or 2 now.

Thanks,
John

Comment: I'm having the same issue, this logger is retarded, it gives no information about the error. A simple 'file X not found' would be enough

Answer (score 8):

Or you can tell rack/cache to shut up in your production.rb:

```
config.action_dispatch.rack_cache[:verbose] = false
```

Answer (score 4):

This is an issue with Rack::Cache: 
[cache: [GET /] miss on default Rails application in production mode Rails 3.2.2](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/5245)

Basically Rack::Cache has its logging set to verbose by default, and its log goes into STDERR, and under Apache STDERR goes into the error log.

As far as I understand, this is completely harmless, not it does fill the error log.

Here is the [patch for this issue](https://github.com/rtomayko/rack-cache/pull/58/files), it has been already merged, so you can either apply it yourself or wait for the next gem update.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem. If you are using the asset pipeline (config.assets.enabled = true in your application.rb) then you should either turn on your on-demand compilation or have all the assets precompiled.

Remember that Rails's helper tags like javascript_include_tag, stylesheet_link_tag, image_tag will try to use the assets path so make sure that all of your assets are available. If any of them is missing then you will get a cache miss.